# LeetCode160-Intersection of Two Linked Lists

Tags: singly-linked-list

This is the first example of the intersection of two linked lists on LeetCode webpage.
The first linked list, A, is [4,1,8,4,5], the second one, B, is [5,6,1,8,4,5]. I found the intersection part of both linked lists is [1,8,4,5]. But the official explanation said "The intersected node's value is 8. From the head of A, it reads as [4,1,8,4,5]. From the head of B, it reads as [5,6,1,8,4,5]. There are 2 nodes before the intersected node in A; There are 3 nodes before the intersected node in B."
Can anyone explain that why the started node of the intersection is "8" instead of "1" in this case?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The image provides important context (taken from https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/):

[image]

You're looking for the point where the two lists start to intersect - this depends on the node connections, not their values. The "1" in both A and B do not imply that they intersect, as the image shows.

Answer (score 2):

i had this same doubt previously, the problem was I was trying to compare the values of nodes, lets say nodeA with a value of 1 and another nodeB with also a value of 1 the problem is if we just compare the nodes in terms of their values we are ignoring the other factors of node like its address, other next elements in node its length, etc. So, instead of matching in terms of nodeA.val == nodeB.val we must be matching in all aspects of a node that is nodeA == nodeB. As shown below:

```
while node1_to_use is not None and node2_to_use is not None:
    if node1_to_use == node2_to_use:   # ignore doing this node1_to_use.val == node2_to_use.val           
        return node2_to_use      

    node1_to_use = node1_to_use.next
    node2_to_use = node2_to_use.next
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the nodes with value 1 in `A` and `B` (2nd node in `A` and 3rd node in `B`) are **different node references**. See:

[image: Example image]

Although it seems that `A[1]` and `B[2]` have the same value, **they point to two different locations in memory**. See:

[image: Memory Example Image]

In this new image, consider what is below the value of the node as a representation of its location in memory. Notice how the memory locations **only become aligned starting from the node with a value of 8**.